# Display data from mysql database to divs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am making a comment system. I know how to insert data in database and how to select it. I am displaying this data in a table and it is working fine. But I want to display every record in new div. How can I create divs and set every comment in new div.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mydiv() {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.width = "500px";
                div.style.height = "100px";
                div.style.background = "black";
                div.style.color = "white";
                div.innerHTML = "";

                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }


<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "commentdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Person");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // This is the div in which i want t diplay data.
    // Should i use innerHTML or something. I totally got confused here.
    echo "mydiv();";
    
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript creating new div for all record in which I have to display data. I am using a js function and echo it with php.

Comment: Show codes that you started

Comment: <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Next time, please use the edit link at the bottom of your question. I've gone ahead and edited your question for you. So what is your question? It's wrapped in a table, so if you want it in a div instead, just change it to `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "peter", "abc123", "my_db"); // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Persons");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>";
        echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";


             echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
      echo "</div>";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Hendry Tanaska you are very talented. Thanks.